# How to retrieve selective properties from the array of objects and store as an object using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to retreive the properties x,y,z from the data structure below and store it in a seperate array.

below is the data structure as logged in console

```
object_arr  [{…}]0: 
     first_property: "color"
     id: 25
     x: 10
     y: 50
     z: 56
    _proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want to get the output as below,
    final_output (3) `{10, 50, 56}`

i have tried using 
    `const final_output = arr_obj.map(m => m.x);`

this returns the x value properly however, when i try below,

```
const final_output = arr_obj.map(m => {m.x; 
                                       m.y;
                                       m.z;});
```

This gives undefined value.

how do i retrieve all three x,y,z values from the above data structure `arr_objects`.

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: so if you have multiple objects, would you want the output to be: `[x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2]`, or would you want them grouped:  `[[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2]]`?

Comment: Your code is not outputting undefined values - It generates an error. Check this error first

Comment: Do you want your final output as an array or an object. Because inside the map method, you wrote object literal and in the question, you said, you want an array like [10, 50, 56] ?

Comment: And since arr_obj is an array of object, do you want x, y and z for each objects or just the first object in that array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the array of objects and then use individual properties.

For example var object_arr[0] -- will give object on the 0th index. And from this object, you can reference properties x, y and z (for example: object_arr[0].x, object_arr[0].y)

Since object_arr is an array you can loop thru it and fetch values.

```
var output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < object_arr.length; i++){
    output.push(
        { 'x' : object_arr[i].x,
          'y': object_arr[i].y,
          'z': object_arr[i].z
        });
}
```

Another way to do this is:

```
var output = [];
object_arr.forEach(function(item, index){
    output.push(
       {
          'x' : item.x,
          'y' : item.y,
          'z' : item.z,
       }
    );
});
```

If you just want an array with those 3 values in it, that can be very straight forward (0 is the index you want to get values of):

```
var output = [object_arr[0].x, object_arr[0].y, object_arr[0].z];
```

If you just need one object and not an array then you can do following:

```
 var output = { 'x' : object_arr[0].x, 'y': object_arr[0].y, 'z': object_arr[0].z };
```

Comment: i want it as an object instead of array. how could it be done.

Comment: Let me modify my solution to add that part too

Comment: @someuser2491 i updated my answer to include this --  var output = { 'x' : object_arr[0].x, 'y': object_arr[0].y, 'z': object_arr[0].z };    this is an object and not an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce:

```
const final_output = arr_obj.reduce((prev, obj) => {
  prev.push(Object.values(obj)); //Just add the values you want here
  return prev;
}, []);
// [[10, 50, 56], ...]
```

Comment: Sry, I have forgotten the 2nd argument (an empty array). `prev` is the value returned by the previous call to the callback provided, The 2nd argument is the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

```
const final_output = arr_obj.map(m => {
  return [
    m.x, 
    m.y,
    m.z
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach and assign to temporary object

```
let newArray = []
arr_obj.forEach((element) => {
newArray.push({x: element.x,y: element.y,z: element.z})
})
```