# How to retrieve property from an array of object and those in a seperate object using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to retrieve certain properties from the array of object and store it in  a array.

the data structure looks like below,

```
object_arr  [{…}]0: 
    first_property: "color"
    id: 25
    x: 10
    y: 50
    z: 56
    _proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

i want to retrieve x, y and z values so the output should be like below

```
(3) [10, 50, 56]
    0: 10
    1: 50
    2: 56
    length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

so final_output[0] should give me 10, final_output[1] should give me 50 and final_output[2] should give 56
```

what i have tried?

```
let final_output = object_arr.map(m => {
       return [
           m.x,
           m.y,
           m.z
       ]
   });
```

the final_output looks like this,

```
final_output [Array(3)]
    0: (3) [10, 50, 56]
    length: 1

 the expected output is as below,

 final_output (3) [10, 50, 56]
     0: 10
     1: 50
     2: 56
     length: 3
```

how can i fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What's the issue with `final_output = final_output[0]`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i have updated the question what final output looks like with the code that i had tried.

Comment: @someuser2491 can you show the expected output when you have multiple objects in your input array (instead of just one)?

Comment: i have updated the question with  expected ouput. i shall have only one object in my input array and is always same.

Comment: I'll just answer the literal question, although i am quite confused about this one: `finalOutput = (({x, y, z}) => [x, y, z])(object_arr[0])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array only contains the one object, you can add its properties directly into an array like so:

```js
const object_arr = [{first_property:"color",id:25,x:10,y:50,z:56}];
const [{x, y, z}] = object_arr; // use destructuring to get the object keys from the array
const res = [x, y, z]; // create an array containing x, y, z properties
console.log(res);
```

If your array can contain multiple objects, you could use `.flatMap()` by mapping your properties to an array, which will then fall into a larger resulting array. This way, all `x`, `y` and `z` properties (of all objects) will be mapped to one larger output array:

```js
const object_arr = [{first_property:"color",id:25,x:10,y:50,z:56}];

const res = object_arr.flatMap(o => [o.x, o.y, o.z]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The `flatMap` version would be odd in the case where there is more than one element in the input array.   It's possibly what would be wanted, with a sequence of `x`, `y`, and `z` values, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I agree. I originally thought it seemed odd and would've imagined that the [solution provided earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58710763/5648954) was enough to fulfil OPs needs. However, it seems as though it wasn't what the OP was after, so I assumed they wanted a flatMap if they're using an array. Overall both questions aren't very clear in my eyes, and so I gave my best estimate at what the OP was after (hence the 2 solutions)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
let object_arr = { first_property: "color", id: 25, x: 10, y: 50, z: 56}
let final_output = [object_arr.x, object_arr.y, object_arr.z];
```

Comment: thanks this should work. can this be done in single statement.

Comment: I don't think that's the input format.  There's an array wrapped around it.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple.  I think your confusion is stemming from trying to work with the input array as a whole.  If you only want the data from its first element, you don't need `map`.  Just address it directly with `[0]`:

```js
let object_arr = [{ first_property: "color", id: 25, x: 10, y: 50, z: 56}]
let final_output = [object_arr [0] .x, object_arr [0] .z, object_arr [0] .z];

console .log (final_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see :
`final_output [Array(3)]
    0: (3) [10, 50, 56]`
which is array of array.
So to get value 10 you will have to do: `final_output[0][0].`
Or `output=final_output[0];`
Then `output[0]`